# Is $(x^2+y^2+x)dx+xydy$ the same as ${dy\over dx}(x^2+y^2+x)+{dx\over dy}(xy)$ ? Is this just a different notation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, notation

Is  $(x^2+y^2+x)dx+xydy$  the same as  ${dy\over dx}(x^2+y^2+x)+{dx\over dy}(xy)$? Is this just a different notation?

Comment: try reading about differentials. Maybe that would help. Btw, its nice to post what you have tried researching before posting a question.

Comment: I have my book "de boeck" about differentials but I didnt find that notation inside of it... And I google my question and find nothing :/ maybe im not using the good words

Comment: Also all posts I found on stackexchange dont talk about the "dx" notation :/

Comment: gochat : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1109193/what-does-a-standalone-dx-mean/1109294#1109294

Thnx

Comment: Its usually very encouraged to always post your thoughts and what you have tried so far. On the surface the questions seems to simply be the difference between a derivative and a differential. Seems like a questions has been asked before, unless you explain what makes your questions different unique.

Comment: Im beginning my Calculus 1 class this semester, I think they will show that soon because I dont understand the difference between a derivative and a differential yet. I think I'll go buy rigth now my book about Calculus I, I can't wait to understand this x) Thnx again

Comment: it doesn't matter what your level is. Research (internet, books or anything) or at least your own thoughts (attempts at solving the problem) are expected before posting a question here. Also, don't write Hello, or things like that in questions. The content of your question is the only thing that matters, please read over the rules of how to use the site for more proper use of it. All questions at whatever level are welcome, as long as they adhere to the rules of the site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolving ODE-1 $(x^2 + y^2 +x)\,dx + xy\,dy=0$ am I wrong or my teacher is?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1643471/resolving-ode-1-x2-y2-x-dx-xy-dy-0-am-i-wrong-or-my-teacher-is)

Comment: @avid19 Let me explain then: obviously, solving the equation (done over there) fully elucidates the notation (asked about here).